# how can i use dataframe and datetimeindex to return rolling 12-month?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetimeindex

Imagine a pandas dataframe with 2 columns (“Manager Returns” and “Benchmark Returns”) and a DatetimeIndex of monthly frequency. Please write a function to calculate the rolling 12-month manager alpha and rolling-12 month tracking error (both annualized).

so far I have this but confused about the rolling-12 month:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#define dummy dataframe with monthly returns
df = pd.DataFrame(1 + np.random.rand(20), columns=['returns'])

#compute 12-month rolling returns
df_roll = df.rolling(window=12).apply(np.prod) - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to calculate the excess return on the 'Manager Returns' compared to the 'Benchmark Returns. First, we create some random data for these two values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
n=20
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Manager=np.random.randint(2, 9, size=n),
    Benchmark=np.random.randint(1, 7, size=n),
    index=pd.date_range("20180101", freq='MS', periods=20)))

df.set_index('index', inplace = True)
```

To calculates the excess return (Alpha), the rolling mean of Alpha and the rolling mean of Tracking Error we create new columns for each value.

```
# Create Alpha
df['Alpha'] = df['Manager'] - df['Benchmark']
# Rolling mean of Alpha
df['Alpha_rolling'] = df['Alpha'].rolling(12).mean()
# Rolling mean of Tracking error
df['TrackingError_rolling'] = df['Alpha'].rolling(12).std()
```

Edit: I see that the values should be annualized, so you would have to transform the monthly returns I guess, my finance lingo is not currently up to date.